# 1 hour countdown in Jpanel?

Tags: java, swing, countdown, countdowntimer

Well i have a Jpanel for a timer, and  i wish to have a countdown timer inside it for 1 hour.

I dont really know how to do it? I have a timer code implemented but i want to write it from scratch, anyone has a template?

I just cant get it to appear, i can make static text appear like "Timer goes here" but a countdown seems impossible for me. Would really appreciate the help. Thanks!

```
private JPanel timer() {
    JPanel timerPanel = new JPanel();
    timerPanel.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    timerPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));

    Countdown(timer, timer);
    JLabel timerLabel = new JLabel("TIMER GOES HERE");
    timerLabel.setFont(new Font("Franklin Gothic Medium", Font.PLAIN, 18));
    timerLabel.setAlignmentX(0);
    timerPanel.add(timerLabel);
    timerPanel.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(10, 10)));

    return timerPanel;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is one way, just enter in how many second you want into the `seconds` field:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class CountdownTimer {
    static int seconds = 100000;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Countdown");
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        final JLabel label = new JLabel();
        panel.add(label);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(500, 500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        Timer timer = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                seconds--;
                int day = (int) TimeUnit.SECONDS.toDays(seconds);
                long hours = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) - (day * 24);
                long minute = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds)
                        - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toHours(seconds) * 60);
                long second = TimeUnit.SECONDS.toSeconds(seconds)
                        - (TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMinutes(seconds) * 60);
                label.setText(hours + " Hour(s), " + minute + " Minute(s) and "
                        + second + " Second(s)");
                if (seconds == 0) {
                    doSomething();
                }
            }
        });
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void doSomething() {
        System.out.println("Something");
    }
}
```

Comment: How do i say put this into a panel inside another frame which i have? Cant seem to do that.

Comment: You would just add the label to something else.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to implement something as basic as a timer, there is `javax.swing.Timer` for that. Just initialize one of those with a 1 second delay, update the label's value, repaint the panel.

Comment: -1, Don't use a util.Timer to update Swing components. Updates to Swing components should be done on the Event Dispatch Thread. So you should be using a Swing Timer. Also, then is no need to repaint the panel. Using setText(...) on the label will the label to repaint itself.